# Node.js exception handler, Designating error if its validation error

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, express, error-handling

I am a newbie in the node.js environment. I used to code dotNet and I am trying to get used to node.js.

Projects that I made in MVC .net, I was using middleware for exception handler and if a validation error occurs I was throwing *CustomException* which has a property describes the error is validation error or not.

I am trying to do this strategy in express.js. I use express-validator

```
router.post("/register", validators, (req, res) => {

    validationResult(req).throw();

    var userDto = req.dto;
    userService.registerUser(userDto)
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).send("User Created Succesfully");
        }).
        catch(err => {
            //log it,
            res.status(500).send("");
        })
})
```

if error occurs experss-validator throws an error with 'Validation failed' message

global error handler like

```
app.use((err,req,res,nex)=>{
    if(err.message ==='Validation failed'){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(422).send(err.array());
    }
    console.log(err);

});
```

As you see in the error handler, I tried to understand if the error is validation error or not by control the error message. It seems ugly, isn't it?

In general, I have not seen this approach in node.js. Could it be the abstraction of single responsibility or something else? It seems node.js tries to keep simple Error stuff. I am suffering that lack of this mechanism. Maybe I am doing anti-pattern but I could not figure it out. If you have a better approach I will immediately give up mine :)

Thanks.

Comment: "*I was throwing a custom exception which has a property that describes whether the error is a validation error or not.*" - you can do exactly the same in JS. Errors are objects, you can assign them any property you want. (You might have to patch/wrap `express-validator` for that though)

Answer (score 1):

In general yes, errors are usually simple in the Node.js world. Unlike C#, you'll typically only see one exception/error type: [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

You are free to create your own error objects (using [ES2015 classes syntax](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html)):

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

Which then you can check the type as you would in C#:

```
const myError = new MyError();
console.log(myError instanceof MyError)
```

However, you don't typically see projects/persons create their own errors. What typically happens is they'll just use the standard `Error` object as is with a specific error message, which you are checking above. However, you are free to add on extra properties (some do this) to help distinguish between `Error` objects:

```
const stdError = new Error()
std.myCustomProperty = 'whoohoo'
```

It is good practice to utilize [error middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) which you are doing to handle errors.

I have a sample MVC style Express project you can look at for a better (IMO) way to handle errors: https://github.com/ciscoo/evaluacion

---

Edit: As of Node.js v10.0.0, all `Error` objects will have a `code` property.

- https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/node-js-errors-changes-you-need-to-know-about-dc8c82417f65
- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/errors.html#errors_node_js_error_codes

Answer (score 0):

You want to catch any validation errors at the controller level, the global error handler is for catching anything your controllers might miss (e.g. 404s).

```
router.post('/register', validators, (req, res) => {

  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped() });
  }

  var userDto = req.dto;
  userService.registerUser(userDto)
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).send("User Created Succesfully");
    }).
    catch(err => {
      //log it,
      res.status(500).send("");
  });
});
```

or alternatively with the throw syntax:

```
router.post('/register', validators, (req, res) => {

  try {
    validationResult(req).throw();
  } catch (errors) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped() });
  }

  var userDto = req.dto;
  userService.registerUser(userDto)
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).send("User Created Succesfully");
    }).
    catch(err => {
      //log it,
      res.status(500).send("");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create custom errors in Javascript, by using the extend the `Error` class

For example:

```js
    class ValidationError extends Error {
      constructor(message) {
        super();
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
        this.message = message;
      }
    }
    
    class NotFoundError extends Error {
      constructor(message) {
        super();
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
        this.message = message;
        this.code = 404;
    
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't put all the text in a code block. It can make it harder to read.